# Whats this new button on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Recently re installed Windows and Chrome and noticed a blue button next to the omnibar:

[image]

It seems to simply refresh the page once pressed.

Then on a Google page it turns into a search icon:

[image]

It seem obvious this might just be a new chrome option to refresh and search, but I can't seem to find any info about it, either on the chrome help site or else where. I also have the latest version of chrome at work and this button doesn't show up

Comment: I also don't have that, and I can't find any documentation from Google or the Chromium project.  Check for added extensions - type in chrome://extensions into the address bar and look for stuff you didn't install.

Comment: Which Chrome version do you have? I presume this is Canary or Beta. Also, I don't quite understand the point of your question – it's quite apparent what the button does, right?

Answer (score 1):

Look's like you've enabled a particular flag in Chrome. Try the following

Type `chrome://flags/#search-button-in-omnibox` into the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then set the highlighted option to disabled and restart your browser.

[image]